# Get Maximum with other data

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have to come and ask this because I'm already angry and crying and everything, because this really kills me. I hate SQL. But it has to be done. Website uses SQL.

I have these tables (shortened to the necessessary and not real SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE deliverer(d_id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE article(a_id INT PRIMATY KEY, brand VARCHAR(80));
CREATE TABLE delivers(d_id FOREIGN KEY(deliverer), a_id FOREIGN KEY(article));
```

I need, for each `brand` those `deliverers` that deliver the most articles. I've come as far as this, after only two hours of mind twisting:

```
SELECT brand, MAX(cnt)
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(a.a_id) AS cnt, a.brand, d.d_id, d.name
    FROM derliverer d, delivers l, article a
    WHERE a.a_id = l.a_id AND l.d_id = d.d_id
    GROUP BY a.brand, d.d_id, d.name)
GROUP BY brand;
```

What I really, really, really don't get about SQL is why it does not let me `GROUP BY brand` ***and*** `SELECT` the `d.name, d.d_id`. It really makes no sense.

Please help me before I jump out of the window.

Comment: I think it was DB2 in production, not sure. Using MySQL in testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I really, really, really don't get about SQL is why it does not let me GROUP BY brand and SELECT the d.name, d.d_id. It really makes no sense.

Because if you do, the count will be for each distinct d.name, d.d_id. This is not what you want.

You definitely want to read some [tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=tutorial+sql+group+by) on how a group by works.

> I need, for each brand those deliverers that deliver the most articles.

In this case you need something like:

```
select brand_id, count(*) as top_deliverer, deliverer_id, deliverer.etc.
from some stuff
group by brand_id, deliverer_id, deliverere.etc
order by top_deliverer desc
```

Comment: Wel, it is valid, but it does not get me the extra data I need. I need to group ny the brand, but also get the d.name with it, without grouping by it. But the `max` function forces me to group by every column.

Comment: Join it with the originating table... Or use two separate queries (will probably be better).

Comment: Follow-up: I've updated my answer accordingly. And based on your reply, you definitely need to read up on that group by statement, because you're completely confused by what it does. You *need* to group by every other column in most databases, and in case you ever end up considering it "coding" optimizations on that using subqueries will lead to a full table scan (which is by far not optimal).

Comment: I hate to ask, but, have you read up on the group by clause as suggested before answering that? I ask, because your comment makes it sound that you're still not understand it. Think of it this way: group by reduces the cartesian join (look at your query before the group by and aggregates) into a new set of rows using aggregate functions based on the fields in the clause. Your understanding seems to be more along the lines of: group by magically returns whatever I want it to irrespective of the fields I want or pass. (And I'm sorry to say, but SQL is not a language that tolerates such fantasy.)

Comment: I did not, sorry. I am too worked up on it, I will give it a rest and read your recommendations. Maybe I just wanted a solution now, because this really gets me worked up. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: No biggy. Just, consider understanding SQL's group by/having clause, because it's obvious you're not "getting it" at the moment. Again, think cartesian product between two sets, reduced by a subset of fields.